# Get list item where sublist can be null

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Hi I have a situation where I have a Car, and Car has many customizations and customizations possibly have many versions.

I am trying to get the car customization if it has a version that versionName contains "xyz".

```
var customizationToBeUpdated = car.Customizations.FirstOrDefault(pv =>
                    pv.Versions.Any(ver =>
                        ver.Name.Contains("xyz")));
```

This code above works when it finds a version that matches, but if it doesn't find throws an exception. Any suggestion on how to deal in the case is null?

***Exception:*** System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Cheers

Comment: Seems like `Versions` is null...

Comment: it is not null. Has an Item. @ZoharPeled. If I explicitly looking for the name of it, it is all good.

Comment: Also "car.Customisations.Where(pv => pv.Versions.Any());" Works fine.

Comment: Than somewhere you have a version where it's `Name` is null.

Comment: Yes. it is... Why is this a problem?

Comment: because `Null.Contains("xyz")` will throw a `NullReferenceException`....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A null safe code would be using the null conditional (`?.`) operator with the null coalescing (`??`) operator.
Something like this:

```
var customizationToBeUpdated = car.Customizations.FirstOrDefault(pv =>
                    pv.Versions?.Any(ver =>
                        ver.Name?.Contains("xyz") ?? false) ?? false);
```

Basically, `pv.Versions?.Any` will only execute `Any` if `Versions` is not null, but if it is null, it will simply return null, same as `Name?.Contains` will only execute `Contains` is `Name` is not null - hence the usage of the `?? false` in both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

### Requirement

You wrote:

> I am trying to get the car customization if it has a version that versionName contains "xyz".

"**The**" car Customization? Does the car have exactly one Customization with this VersionName?

- Car A has three Customizations: K, L, M
- K has one Version: "1.0"
- L has two Versions: "1.0" and "2.0"
- M has three Versions: "1.0" "1.1" "2.0"

Give me "the" Customization of Car A that has a version "1.0".

### Classes

Alas you forgot to give us your classes. If you've followed the [entity framework code first conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) you'll have classes like this:

```
class Car
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // Every Car has zero or more Customizations (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Customization> Customizations {get; set;}
}

class Customization
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // Every Customization belongs to exactly one Car, using foreign key
    public int CarId {get; set;}
    public virtual Car Car {get; set;}

    // Every Customization has zero or more Versions (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Version> Versions {get; set;}
}

class Version
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // Every Version belongs to exactly one Customization, using foreign key
    public int CustomizationId {get; set;}
    public virtual Customization Customization {get; set;}
}
```

This is all that entity framework needs to detect the one-to-many relations.

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented using non-virtual properties; the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

Hence a foreign key is non-virtual; the object that the foreign key refers to is virtual.

### Back to your question

**Requirement**: Given a `car` and a `versionName`, give me all `Customizations` of this Car that has at least one `Version` with a `Name` equal to this `VersionName`

```
Car car = ...
string versionName = ...
```

You can start at Customizations or at Versions:

**Start at Customizations:** Give me the Customizations of my Car that has at least one Version with a Name equal to versionName:

```
var result = dbContext.Customizations
    .Where(customization => 
        // it is one of the customization of my car:
        customization.CarId == car.Id

        // and this customization has at least one Version with versionName:
        customization.Versions.Where(version => version.Name == versionName))
                              .Any());
```

You can also start at Versions:
From every Version that has a Name equal to versionName and a Customization of my car, give me some properties of the Customization:

```
var result = dbContext.Versions

    // keep only the Versions that have the correct VersionName
    // and that is a Customization of my car:
    .Where(version => version.Name == versionName
                   && version.Customization.CarId == car.Id)

    // from the remaining Versions Select the properties that you plan to use
    .Select(version => new
    {
         // Select the Customization properties that you want:
         Id = version.Customization.Id,
         CustomizationCode = version.Customization.Code,
         ...
    });
```